# Clara wants to feed a zombie head? Why?

Tags: the-walking-dead

Clara wanted to feed a head? but the head had no stomach.  She says that "the head" was getting weak.  Why do the zombies eat? Do they starve to death if they are already dead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In The Walking Dead, what happens to zombies that don't eat?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11332/in-the-walking-dead-what-happens-to-zombies-that-dont-eat)

Comment: Because she is crazy?

Comment: Not voting to close because the question in the title is not a dup of "What happens to zombies that don't eat?", but recommend the OP delete the second (& third) question(s) from the body of the post.

Answer (score 4):

SPOILERS!

If you haven't seen the most recent episode of the Walking Dead (S04E01 - 30 Days Without An Accident), don't read past this point.

> Clara is clearly insane with grief. Her a lack of adjustment to the Zombie Apocalypse was partially due to her reluctance to fight. Unlike Rick's group, she and her companion were unable to join a group successfully. She seemed to be in a state of similar to a nervous breakdown and ultimately kills herself when she was unable to kill Rick.

So...

> As she lay dying, and she is answering Rick's Three Questions, we discover she has never killed a human being or a walker, leaving all of that work to her now-dead companion. The woman was clearly unstable and unlikely to have been able to fully integrate into any kind of normal society even by the Zombie Apocalypse standards...