# How do zombies get nourishment from eating?

Tags: zombie

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Happens to Zombies that Don't Eat?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8206/what-happens-to-zombies-that-dont-eat)

I assume zombies don't have blood flow, since they can't be stopped with a shot in the heart.

If so, how is it possible they can maintain their strength by eating? The proteins of the fresh meat requires a blood flow to be extracted in the bowels, right?

Or is it generally understood that zombies only eat out of habit and eventually lose strength and rot with less and less movement and danger for the still living as a result?

Answer (score 5):

They do not have strength. They are pushed towards eating (other people) by the resources they have left in their sick bodies. The virus or bacteria that causes 'zombiism', pushes them forward to spread the infection, until they cannot longer live. Keep in mind that the virus (or bacteria) spends the resources in the body in an optimized manner, so they can 'survive' long enough to infect other healthy organisms.

EDIT:
'Eating', or should I say biting, is just the means to transfer the disease. The easiest method of blood transfer between humans, also the easiest to provoke, using the hunger instinct.