# Are elderly zombies created from aged citizens less robust than zombies created from younger humans?

Tags: the-walking-dead

Has the Walking Dead canon addressed zombie ageism and featured old people zombies? Are the zombies that used to be elderly people less robust than the zombies created from younger people, or are they just as functional?

Comment: Given the nature of the change and how muscles assumedly work afterwards, I would say that NO, initially there's no (or very little) difference between a middle-aged victim and an elderly victim. That said, bones may be more brittle and/or as Shev alluded to below, the post-infected form may deteriorate at a faster rate.

Answer (score 1):

There hasn't been any mention as to whether elderly people make weaker zombies. AFAIR, we haven't seen any elder person turn; or we have seen and there wasn't any mention of it. *But* we have seen child zombies, so I guess elderly zombies exist too.

But, as with child zombies, we don't know if they are weaker or not since there hasn't been any such mention.

Now, as far as zombie ageism goes, there has been another question here: [Does a Walker's senses diminish with time?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71622/does-a-walkers-senses-diminish-with-time)

Where I answered with a quote of Kirkman's on [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/20u6xf/im_robert_kirkman_creator_of_the_walking_dead_ama/cg6sbq8):

> **OddGuyOut**: In the beginning of the show we saw walkers do things like using a rock to help bash the doors in or turning a door knob, is there a reason we've stopped seeing them do that?
>
> **Robert Kirkman**: Older zombies are less together and capable or doing things like that. Fresher zombies, which there were more of in season one, are able to do more than older, more rotted zombies.

Which simply says that, yes, zombies do age and they are not as strong as they used to be.

Comment: Sorry - The question referred to zombies who were elderly before they became zombies. The quote given refers to zombies which have been dead for a long time, and have decayed. The first distinction is between young/old, the second between fresh/rotted. Not the same.

Comment: What about the 'zombie ageism' part?

Comment: Did you read the first part of my answer where I talk about elderly people? Maybe you should see the whole answer instead of just the quote

Comment: We do see an elderly man pass away from natural causes and reanimate in S03E07. Andrea has to save Milton from being overpowered.