# In the Walking Dead, do older more decrepit zombies retain their eyesight?

Tags: comics, the-walking-dead

Whenever we see a close up of a zombie's face, their eyes always appear to be a [milky white / brown colour](http://media.moddb.com/images/groups/1/9/8657/1008823_725574620802032_761075201_o.jpg), which would lead me to believe they are blind.

And, I'm assuming, they don't produce tears, so their eyes should be damaged beyond use anyway. But it seems as if they can see reasonably well, at least well enough to distinguish a person from something else.

They probably use sound and smell to track targets, but I've seen episodes where they are distracted by flares or fires, so they have to be able to see well enough to spot a fire in the distance.

This question : [Does a Walker's senses diminish with time?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71622/does-a-walkers-senses-diminish-with-time) addresses a zombie's senses and if they diminish over time. I would be more interested in *older* zombies, as their eyes should really be damaged beyond any use.

Is their eyesight ever addressed or explained in the show or in the comics?

Comment: As mentioned in the other question, they are shown to use rocks early on in the show. Unless that rock smelled, there's little chance one could figure out to pick it up and use it.

Comment: @phantom42 yes but that's when they're _young_ zombies and their eyes would still function normally and look fine. I'm asking about _older_ zombies with damaged or ruined eyes, they still seem to be able to see quite well.

Comment: I'm not following you. You've seen evidence that they can see (tracking flares and fires). The other question explains that their senses and reasoning diminish over time. How are you confused if they're blind, when you yourself say that they can see?

Comment: @phantom42 lol... I'm not confused at all, their eyes are damaged to the point where they shouldn't be able to see, yet they can see. I'm asking if it has ever been explained in canon, does their sight change in some way or can they detect heat, something like that.

Comment: Then I'd suggest updating your title which explicitly asks if they are blind.